# Tensorflow deep learning Weird Accuracy

Tags: python, deep-learning, tensorflow

I want to build a model to classify images of a dataset( ASL signs alphabet ).

The dataset is in a folder where each sub-folder contains the images of a class and the name of the class is the name the sub-folder. Each image is 200x200.

I wrote two scripts. The first one to transform the dataset to TFrecords. Here it is :

```
import glob
import numpy as np
from random import shuffle
import cv2
from tqdm import tqdm
import tensorflow as tf

#dataset file
dataset_file=glob.glob("dataset/asl_alphabet_train/*")


features_add=[]
labels=[]
classes_names=[]
img_size=100

#getting the addess of each image and its label and the name of each class
#the label will be the same as the index of the corresponding classe name : classes_names(label[i]) is the name of the classes of the image i 
for i,f in enumerate(dataset_file):
    classes_names.append(f[27:]) # the name of the subfolders is the name of the class
    subfolder_paths=glob.glob(f+"/*")
    for j,sub_f in enumerate(subfolder_paths):
        labels.append(i) # the label is the same for all the images in the subfolder
        features_add.append(sub_f)

features_add=np.asarray(features_add)
labels=np.asarray(labels)
classes_names=np.asarray(classes_names)

# shuffle the data 
tmp=list(zip(features_add, labels))
shuffle(tmp)
features_add, labels=zip(*tmp)

#Divide the data into 70% train, 20% validation and 10% test
train_add=features_add[0:int(0.7*len(features_add))]
train_labels=labels[0:int(0.7*len(features_add))]

val_add=features_add[int(0.7*len(features_add)):int(0.9*len(features_add))]
val_labels=labels[int(0.7*len(features_add)):int(0.9*len(features_add))]

test_add=features_add[int(0.9*len(features_add)):]
test_labels=labels[int(0.9*len(features_add)):]

def read_image(add):
    #read an image
    #no need to resize, all the images in this dataset are 200x200
    #cv2 images in BGR, it doesn't really matter for our netword
    img= cv2.imread(add)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (img_size, img_size), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    img=img.astype(np.float32)#/255
    #img = np.asarray(img)
    return img


def _int64_feature(value):
    #convert value to int64 using tf.train.Int64List and creature a feature using tf.train.Feature
    return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))

def _bytes_feature(value):
    #convert value to bytes using tf.train.BytesList and creature a feature using tf.train.Feature
    return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))

def TFrecord_write(features_add,labes, name):
    # data->FeatureSet->Example protocol-> Serialized Example -> tfRecord
    with tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter("TFrecords/"+name+".tfrecords") as writer: # the TFwriter writer
        print("writing the "+name+" TFrecord")
        for i,add in enumerate(tqdm(features_add)):
            img_raw=read_image(add)
            height=img_raw.shape[0]
            width=img_raw.shape[1]
            depth=img_raw.shape[2]
            img_raw=img_raw.tostring()# convert each image to bytes
            example= tf.train.Example(
                features=tf.train.Features(
                    feature={
                        'label': _int64_feature(int(labels[i])),
                        'img_raw': _bytes_feature(tf.compat.as_bytes(img_raw))
                    }))
            writer.write(example.SerializeToString())

#write the record
TFrecord_write(train_add,train_labels,"train")
TFrecord_write(val_add,val_labels,"val")
TFrecord_write(test_add,test_labels,"test")
```

And the second script is where I read the TFrecords, define the model and train it, and the evaluate it. Here It's :

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import glob
import sys
import math

batch_size = 3
img_size = 100
classes_names = []
dataset_file = glob.glob("dataset/asl_alphabet_train/*")


for f in dataset_file:
    classes_names.append(f[27:])  #  the name of the subfolders is the name of the class
num_classes = len(classes_names)


def parser(record):
    # a parsing function to parse the tfrecords
    keys_to_features = {
        "img_raw": tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        "label": tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)

    }
    parsed = tf.parse_single_example(record,
                                     keys_to_features)  # parsing one example from the example buffer from the tfrecord using the keys
    image = tf.decode_raw(parsed["img_raw"], tf.float32)  # decoding ( bytes -> tf.float32)
    image= tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
    image = tf.reshape(image, shape=[img_size, img_size, 3])  # reshaping images
    label = parsed["label"]  # casting labels to int32
    label = tf.one_hot(indices=label, depth=num_classes) # transform to one hot encoding
    # with tf.Session() as session:
    #     print(session.run(label))
    return image, label


def input_fn(filenames, train_bool=True):
    # from tfrecord to iterable data
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames=filenames,
                                      num_parallel_reads=40)  # instantiantion of an object from class TFRecordDataset
    dataset = dataset.map(parser)  # maps a function to the dataset
    if train_bool:
        #dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=2048)
        repeat = 1  # if in training mode allow reading data infinitely
    else:
        repeat = 1  # if in validation or test allow max 1 read
    dataset = dataset.repeat(repeat)
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)  #  define bach size
    # iterator= dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()# making the iterator
    # images_batch, labels_batch=iterator.get_next()# getting the data
    # x= {'image': images_batch}
    # y= labels_batch

    return dataset  # x, y

def train_input_fn():
    return input_fn(filenames=["TFrecords/train.tfrecords"])

def val_input_fn():
    return input_fn(filenames=["TFrecords/val.tfrecords"],train_bool=False)

def test_input_fn():
    return input_fn(filenames=["TFrecords/test.tfrecords"])

def conv_layer_max2pool(Input, num_output_channels, conv_filter_size,conv_strides, pool_filter_size, pool_strides):
    # a function to create convulional layers, parameters are :
    #       num_output_channels : number of the output filters
    #       conv_filters_size: size of the convolution filter it should be a 2-D tuple
    #       conv-strides: strides of the convolution. It's assumes that the strides over the height are the same as over the width
    #       pool_filter_strides: as the conv_filter_size but for the pooling filter
    #       pool_strides: as the conv_strides but for the pooling

    filter_shape= [conv_filter_size[0], conv_filter_size[1], Input.get_shape().as_list()[3], num_output_channels] #creating the shape of the filter to create the weights of the convolution
    W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(filter_shape, stddev=0.01)) #creating the weights
    conv= tf.nn.conv2d(Input, W, [1,conv_strides,conv_strides,1], padding="SAME") # creating the convolutional layer

    bias=tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_output_channels])) # creating the biasis

    conv=tf.nn.bias_add(conv, bias)
    conv=tf.nn.relu(conv)

    #max pooling
    conv=tf.nn.max_pool(conv, [1, pool_filter_size[0], pool_filter_size[1], 1],[1, pool_strides, pool_strides, 1], padding="SAME")

    return conv

def model_fn(X, keep_prob):

    conv1=conv_layer_max2pool(X,num_output_channels=64, conv_filter_size=(5,5), conv_strides=2, pool_filter_size=(2,2), pool_strides=2)

    conv1= tf.nn.dropout(conv1, keep_prob)

    conv2=conv_layer_max2pool(conv1,num_output_channels=128, conv_filter_size=(3,3), conv_strides=2, pool_filter_size=(2,2), pool_strides=2)

    conv2= tf.nn.dropout(conv2, keep_prob)

    # conv3 = conv_layer_max2pool(conv2, num_output_channels=128, conv_filter_size=(3, 3), conv_strides=2,
    #                             pool_filter_size=(2, 2), pool_strides=2)
    #
    # conv4 = conv_layer_max2pool(conv3, num_output_channels=128, conv_filter_size=(2, 2), conv_strides=2,
    #                             pool_filter_size=(2, 2), pool_strides=2)





    flat_layer= tf.layers.flatten(conv2)

    #FC layers

    dense1=tf.layers.dense(flat_layer, 256, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    dense2=tf.layers.dense(dense1, 128, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    dense3=tf.layers.dense(dense2, 64, activation=tf.nn.relu)

    #output layer
    output=tf.layers.dense(dense3, num_classes)
    return output


#Remove previous weights, bias, inputs...
tf.reset_default_graph()

# place holdes for features, labels and keep_prob
x=tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, img_size, img_size, 3] , name="X")
y=tf.placeholder(tf.int64, [None, num_classes], name="y")
keep_prob=tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name="keep_prob")


#logits
logits= tf.identity(model_fn(x, keep_prob), name="logits")

# loss=
loss=tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits( labels=y, logits=logits))

#optimizer
optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)

#Accuracy
pred=tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits,1),tf.argmax(y,1))
accuracy=tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(pred,tf.float32), name="accuracy")


train_dataset= train_input_fn()
train_iterator=train_dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
features, labels= train_iterator.get_next()

valid_dataset=val_input_fn()
valid_iterator=valid_dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
valid_features, valid_labels=valid_iterator.get_next()


save_model_path="Model/model0/"

epochs= 10
keep_probability=0.5

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    #num_images=train_input_fn().get_shape().as_list[0]
    #training_cycle
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        #for _ in range(math.ceil(num_images/batch_size)):
        sess.run(train_iterator.initializer)
        sess.run(valid_iterator.initializer)
        count=0
        while True  :
            try:
                count += 1
                img_batch, label_batch= sess.run([features,labels])
                # print([classes_names[i] for i in label_batch])
                # #input()
                # for i,test in enumerate(img_batch):
                #     #print(label_batch)#classes_names[label_batch[1]])
                #     test2 = Image.fromarray(img_batch[i].astype('uint8'), 'RGB')
                #     test2.show(test2)
                #     input()
                # print("next batch")
                sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: img_batch, y: label_batch, keep_prob: keep_probability})
                #print("batch number :", count)
            except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
                break

        print('Epoch {:>2}: '.format(epoch+1),end='')
        l = sess.run(loss, feed_dict={x: img_batch, y: label_batch, keep_prob: 1.0})
        count=0
        valid_accuracy=0
        while True :
            try:
                valid_img_batch, valid_label_batch = sess.run([valid_features, valid_labels])
                valid_accuracy+=sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: valid_img_batch, y:valid_label_batch, keep_prob:1.0})
            except  tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
                break
            count+=1
        valid_accuracy=valid_accuracy/count
        print("The loss is : {0}, and the Validation Accuracy is: {1}".format(l, valid_accuracy))

    saver=tf.train.Saver()
    saver_path=saver.save(sess,save_model_path)
```

The problem is , no matter how I change the model, no matter how I change the batch_size or even change the optimizer, and no matter how long I run the training I get always the same accuracy : arround 3%.

I still can't figure it out why. 
Can you help?

Thank you

Comment: What is the value of learning rate? If learning rate value is too small, parameters never get updated.

Comment: I don't think it's a learning rate problem. I tried different values ( 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001. The accuracy stays the same !!